# After building the probability space, how to motivate for random variables?

Tags: statistics

Having put my audience through developing a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space of a random trial, $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field on it, and P is a measure on that $\sigma$-field, how to I motivate shifting the whole construct to the real line?

And while I'm at it, how do I justify it informally, i.e., without heavy math? I know (I think, but I'm a bit fuzzy) that a random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ induces a Borel field but even if I'm right about that how does that convince the listener that the whole probability space is ported to the real line?

Comment: Is this a course for mathematicians or for people who apply probability theory?

Comment: General answer:  Get a good textbook and follow it.  There are many levels of probability courses.   Some do not talk about "probability space" at all.

Comment: What do you want to motivate and justify, exactly? The definition of a random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, the notion of its distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, the notion of $X$-measurable events, or something else? In any case, I don't see heavy math involved except for the things you already take for granted - i.e. being familiar with measures and measurability.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelBächtold, there is no answer for this question if the course audience is not specified.

Comment: I imagine the best answer will be a combination of @GeraldEdgar 's comment and a specific textbook.

Comment: $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ does not induce a Borel field. The Borel field of a topological space is the smallest sigma algebra containing the open sets. The Borel field of $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) is what it is.  The definition of a real random variable is that $X$ is "measurable", which means that the pre-image of any Borel set is an elment of $\mathcal{F}$. So I would say that you don't need to convince the listener that this is the case - you just declare it to be part of the definition of a real random variable.  Of course, to aid understanding I would give good examples.

Comment: try to ask students to construct a complicated probability space (or maybe infinite probability space?) and motivate why maybe we might need random variables

Comment: @joe helpful and clear. I accept the question is ill-formed. The audience? Juniors or seniors who plan to pursue grad studies in areas like economics with a focus on econometrics. Although a grasp of set-theoretic prob. theory is not required, it surely would be helpful.  Motivate? There you are sitting in class learning all about $P(E)$  and $P(A \cup B)$ and conditional P and Bayes. Suddenly, the prof. says image an $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and suddenly all the other stuff, having strutted and fretted it's hour upon the stage ... is heard no more.

Comment: @Lenny: I think you might have the right idea. Thank you.